# How do I test the case, when a mocked object does not return an error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

In class `ClassToTest.java` I have the following method:

```
private Optional<SomeObject> getObjById(String id) {
    Optional<SomeObject> obj = someApi.getById(id);
    if (!obj.isPresent()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid id: " + id);
    }
    return obj;
  }
```

The private method `getObjById(String id)` is called within the public method `callMyMethod` of `ClassToTest`.

I want to write two test scenarios - one, when the id is not presented and I am throwing an error. This was easy, I wrote it and my test pass:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void shouldThrowAnErrorIfIdIsNotPresented(){
      Object1 obj1 = new Object1(");

      testee.callMyMethod(obj1);
  }
```

The other case is difficult for me. I want to test that if the id is present, it won't return an error. The service `someApi` is mocked and injected inside `ClassToTest`.  It has the following api:

```
@Service
public class SomeApi {
  @Autowired
  private ObjectManager objectManager;
  @Autowired
  private OtherApi otherApi;

  public SomeObject get(String id) {
    return objectManager.fetch(id, OtherParam...);
  }

  public Optional<SomeObject> getByName(String name) {
    return objectManager.fetchAll(someParams)
                        .findFirst();
  }

  public Set<Obj> findByOtherParam(OtherParam param) {
          .................
  }

  }
}
```

Basically, only getters. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Create a test method call the code under test and if you make it to the end of the test method without the exception being thrown, it passed.

Comment: so I am not verifying.asserting anything?

Comment: `doReturn(Optional.of(new SomeObject())).when(mockSomeApi).getByName(anyString());`?

Comment: Assert that the return value isn’t null in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When I did mock testing and wanted to check if my object (which was a valid object) was persisted in DB I used: verify(someApi).method(someObject);
That will check if the method was actually called.
You can try like that or just check if service.getById dosent return null

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to configure your mock `SomeApi` instance to return something more helpful when that method is called.

```
@Test
public void testSuccessCase() {
    // Can replace 'anyString' with specific String if you know it.
    doReturn(Optional.of(new SomeObject())).when(mockSomeApi).getById(anyString());

    testee.callMyMethod(thingThatWillGiveAboveId);

    // Some verification on what happened as a result...
}
```